# OpenSSl not found Unity3D

Tags: facebook, hash, sdk, openssl, unity-game-engine

We are trying to use Facebook's SDK, we installed the 4.3.6 version for Unity3D(4.3).
We also installed OpenSSL v1.0.1e 64x (we copied the content of the bin folder of openSSL to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin)

We have Windows 7 64-bit.
We also made a new app in the fb developers web (with the id number and everything)

We tried all the things listed here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/543593/unity-facebook-sdk-android-deployement-key-hash-.html

But the Hash Key doesn't appear in the Facebook Editor.(Unity can't find OpenSSL)

The error is "OpenSSL not found. Make sure that openSSL is installed, and that it is in your path"

How can we fix this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was also facing this same problem and I solved it by putting my java bin path to Environment Variables --> System Variable --> Path

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\  (place '\' after bin as well)

you can test you path by typing java in cmd

or

just put the path of openssl folder to
Environment Variables --> System Variable --> Path

d:\OPENSSL_FOLDER\bin\

Comment: Thanks for answering.

what should the variable name of the java or openssl path be?

Thanks!

Comment: Environment Variables --> System Variable --> append your java and openssl path in 'PATH' existing variable

Comment: Install openssl here: https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html